# Double groupby in pandas: how to get category with maximum value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transaction dataframe where the customers are categorized as rich and poor.

I want to see if it's mostly rich or poor people going to each shop.

```
print(df.sample(10))


           Shop  Transaction_value Social Group
7           KFC                  7         Rich
22  Burger King                342         Rich
19  Burger King                  6         Rich
5           KFC                  2         Poor
14    McDonalds                245         Rich
2           KFC                  3         Poor
16    McDonalds                 56         Poor
6           KFC                  6         Poor
20  Burger King                 23         Poor
8           KFC                  5         Poor
```

I have made it most of the way:

```
df.groupby(['Shop', 'Social Group'])["Transaction_value"].count()


Shop         Social Group
Burger King  Poor            7
             Rich            3
KFC          Poor            6
             Rich            3
McDonalds    Poor            3
             Rich            6
```

I can see that Burger King attracts mostly poor people. And McDonalds attracts mostly rich people.

But how can I extract just that information? i.e. the social group that goes to each shop the most.

I am trying to get a result like this:

```
Shop         Social Group
Burger King  Poor                 
KFC          Poor            
McDonalds    Rich
```

I have check some other questions here that use `idxmax()` but I couldn't get it to work:

```
df.groupby(['Shop', 'Social Group'])["Transaction_value"].count().idxmax()

('Burger King', 'Poor')
```

I have also used `max()` unsuccessfully:

```
df.groupby(['Shop', 'Social Group'])["Transaction_value"].count().max(level=0)


Shop
Burger King    7
KFC            6
McDonalds      6
```

Any advice?

My df:

```
df.to_dict()

{'Shop': {0: 'KFC',
  1: 'KFC',
  2: 'KFC',
  3: 'KFC',
  4: 'KFC',
  5: 'KFC',
  6: 'KFC',
  7: 'KFC',
  8: 'KFC',
  9: 'McDonalds',
  10: 'McDonalds',
  11: 'McDonalds',
  12: 'McDonalds',
  13: 'McDonalds',
  14: 'McDonalds',
  15: 'McDonalds',
  16: 'McDonalds',
  17: 'McDonalds',
  18: 'Burger King',
  19: 'Burger King',
  20: 'Burger King',
  21: 'Burger King',
  22: 'Burger King',
  23: 'Burger King',
  24: 'Burger King',
  25: 'Burger King',
  26: 'Burger King',
  27: 'Burger King'},
 'Transaction_value': {0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 3,
  3: 34,
  4: 2,
  5: 2,
  6: 6,
  7: 7,
  8: 5,
  9: 4,
  10: 3,
  11: 2,
  12: 12,
  13: 31,
  14: 245,
  15: 123,
  16: 56,
  17: 67,
  18: 68,
  19: 6,
  20: 23,
  21: 44,
  22: 342,
  23: 234,
  24: 3,
  25: 234,
  26: 666,
  27: 88},
 'Social Group': {0: 'Poor',
  1: 'Rich',
  2: 'Poor',
  3: 'Poor',
  4: 'Rich',
  5: 'Poor',
  6: 'Poor',
  7: 'Rich',
  8: 'Poor',
  9: 'Rich',
  10: 'Rich',
  11: 'Rich',
  12: 'Rich',
  13: 'Rich',
  14: 'Rich',
  15: 'Poor',
  16: 'Poor',
  17: 'Poor',
  18: 'Poor',
  19: 'Rich',
  20: 'Poor',
  21: 'Poor',
  22: 'Rich',
  23: 'Poor',
  24: 'Poor',
  25: 'Rich',
  26: 'Poor',
  27: 'Poor'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution is possible chain another `groupby` by first level with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), get list of tuples (because `MultiIndex`), so select second values by indexing with `str[1]`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Shop', 'Social Group'])["Transaction_value"]
       .count()
       .groupby(level=0)
       .idxmax()
       .str[1]
       .reset_index(name='Social Group'))

print (df1)
          Shop Social Group
0  Burger King         Poor
1          KFC         Poor
2    McDonalds         Rich
```

Another idea is use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) which sorting by default, so is selected first index value:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Shop')["Social Group"]
        .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
        .reset_index(name='Social Group'))

print (df1)

          Shop Social Group
0  Burger King         Poor
1          KFC         Poor
2    McDonalds         Rich
```

Or solution with [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and selecting first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Shop')["Social Group"]
        .agg(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
        .reset_index(name='Social Group'))

print (df1)
          Shop Social Group
0  Burger King         Poor
1          KFC         Poor
2    McDonalds         Rich
```